# JRuby Array to Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, jruby

I am making a site in JRuby on Rails, I am using some Java classes as well.

I have a select form element which passes user selections to the controller.

The selections are passed like so:

```
Parameters: {"options"=>["Option One", "Option Two"]}
```

The Java method that I am using requires the options selected to be a `String[]` (Java String Array?)

I have tried using:

```
params[:options].to_java(:string)
```

This does not seem to work.  Can someone point out what I am doing wrong and what I need to do convert the options to a Java String Array?

Thanks

Eef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`params[:options]` is a different key from `params["options"]`, perhaps you really want `params["options"]`?

With that change, your code seems to work in `jirb`:

```
$ jirb --simple-prompt
>>  {"options"=>["Option One", "Option Two"]}["options"].to_java :string
=> [Ljava.lang.String;@107f742
>>
```

Comment: when you hit the submit button I have generally accessed anything passed to the controller with params, params[:options], I will your solution a try, thanks.