# Calling a static java method from jruby where one of the static method's parameters is a java interface

Tags: java, interface, jruby

I'm working with a Java API which contains several overloaded functions of the form

`class Someclass ...`

`public static A fun(AInterface,java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[],double[][])`

`public static A fun(AInterface,java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[][])`

Pseudocode b/c I don't have the code in front of me.  Now, I'm trying to call this function from jruby.  My calling code looks something like this:

`Someclass::fun(@b, ["foo"], ["bar"], [["baz"], ["qux"]])`

`@b` is an instance of `A`; `A` implements the `AInterface` interface.

Yet I'm getting

`NameError: no method 'fun' for arguments (my.thing.A,org.jruby.RubyArray,org.jruby.RubyArray,org.jruby.RubyObject) on Java::mything::A
  available overloads:
    (my.thing.AInterface,java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[],double[][])
    (my.thing.AInterface,java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[][])
...`

Changing the calling code to:

`Someclass::fun(@b, [["foo"]].to_java(java.lang.String[]), [["bar"]].to_java(java.lang.String[]), [["baz"], ["qux"]].to_java(java.lang.String[][]))`

does not help.

Comment: Create actual Java arrays, as per http://thinkincode.net/2010/12/29/jruby-to-java-by-example.html.

Comment: @DaveNewton please see my response.  I think the problem is related to the interface and overloading, and not the types of the arrays.

Comment: Is the error message the same? How are you creating your A?

Comment: Maybe  `.to_java(:string)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532606/jruby-array-to-java-array